# NotSerializableException - FacesCtrlActionBinding

Tags: oracle-adf, business-process-management

We are using some adf internal classes to control our views, we are working on a clustering environment, the problem
is that sometimes the view page get some errors and in the log shows:

```
2017-11-14T09:42:15.424-02:00] [adf_server1] [ERROR] [] [oracle.adfinternal.controller.state.SessionBasedScopeMap] [tid: [ACTIVE].[[
java.io.NotSerializableException: oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.model.binding.FacesCtrlActionBinding
```

Weblogic 12.1.3.0.0 ADF 12c

Does anybody know how can I make adf internal classes serializable or have another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These classes usually uses internal representation of the components, which are not serializable. 
I would suggest to not use any ADF internal classes, since:

1) You will get warnings in JDeveloper
2) It is hard to control it!

However if you must, I would wrap declare these members as ***transient*** (to solve the serialization problem (that means this property will not be high available).

Comment: Looking at full stack strace I realized the error occurs between the page and binding variables, at this point I don't have any layer, it's all generated automatically by JDeveloper. I'm only using pageFlow and request scope at all.

Comment: In that case there is nothing to be done, this errors usually appears in a lot of logs but have no impact on the application or its stability.

Comment: Analisyng the error I saw it's not related to this behavior, I think it's only a warn this message, the real error is because the session has timed out. I know that is related to cluster because when I leave just one server up everething works. Thank you @Amr Gawish